# mvn jetty:run looking for a file that doesn't exist

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, jetty

I've been learning the basics of Spring MVC by writing a very simple CRUD app and running it with Jetty. (I've been following a mix of this [mkyong tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/) and [this journaldev tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/3531/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-integration-crud-example-tutorial))

When I run `mvn compile` it compiles without error. But when I start jetty with `mvn jetty:run`, I get

```
A required class was missing while executing org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.2.11.v20150529:run: Lcom/mkyong/model/stock/StockDao;
```

Technically it's correct because I don't store the stock DAO at that path. It's at `com/mkyong/dao/StockDAO.java`.

But obviously something, somehwere, seems to be referencing it at that path it's complaining about? It's a small app and I've combed it several times and pulled out some hair in frustration trying to find it. I'm still incredibly new at debugging java so the verbosity of the errors is really confusing as well.

[Here is the full source code of the app](https://github.com/abhchand/java-hello-world-spring-mvc-xml). Any thoughts on where the issue might be?

Thanks so much!!

**EDIT:**

Adding screenshots to address a comment below.

Github appears to lowercase parts of the word `Dao` in the filename, but they are most definitely all upper case on my local machine

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The names of some public classes differ from their related source files. Change StockDao.java to StockDAO.java and StockDaoImpl.java to StockDAOImpl.java.

Comment: Thanks for a taking a look! Something kind of strange - the filename on github is listed as `StockDao.java` but on my local machine it's `StockDAO.java`. Same with the other file. Added screenshots to the post. That issue aside, still curious why it would  be looking in another completely different folder (`model/`)

Comment: @user2490003 I find it hard to believe that GitHub alters your files. Are you sure the files are named correctly on disk and that your editor doesn't give you a false perception, e.g. what does your Windows explorer say? I can run mvn jetty:run just fine on your GitHub project after changing the file names.

Comment: @user2490003 Regarding the wrong package error, I'd suggest to use *mvn clean install* to build the project instead of *mvn compile*. It could be that your target folder is polluted with old compiled classes that no longer exist and cleaning your project helps remove them.

Comment: I just cloned the repo and executed `mvn jetty:run`. It failed due to the naming issue @luc14n0 identified. I then changed the name of the files and the app ran successfully. I recommend you recreate your dev environment.

Comment: Thanks @luc14n0. It was definitely fixed by using `clean`. Specifically I went with `mvn clean compile` since I didn't want to run `test`, `verify`, `install`, etc...